# Атака на шифр методом перестановки

Tags: python, python-3.x, криптография

Всем салют. Необходимо совершить **атаку** на зашифрованный **методом перестановки** текст. Вкратце, даётся ключ, к примеру 321 и из текста "АБВГДЕЁЖЗ" мы получим "ВБАЕДГЗЖЁ". Атаку нужно совершить, не зная ключа шифрования. Если возможно, был бы рад коду с комментариями.
P.S. Имеется словарь с наиболее часто встречающимися словами (и, по, что, как, так, я, в, не, и т.д.). Программа должна сверяться с этим словарём.

Comment: а как можно убедиться, что найденный ключ валидный? программы не умеют отслеживать логику в сообщениях и понимать, что есть набор слов\букв, а что нет, или дается конечная фраза?

Comment: Да, забыл добавить, есть словарь с наиболее распространёнными словами, такими как: я, по, что, как, нет, или и т.д. Программа должна проверять соответствует ли расшифрованное слово какому либо слову из словаря и, в случае если да, это значит что ключ подобран и на вывод можно подать расшифрованный этим ключом текст.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: 1251 -*-
import os, sys
s1 = 'ВБАЕДГЗЖЁ'
s2 = 'АБВГДЕЁЖЗ'
key = ''
len_s1 = len (s1)
i = 0
j = 0

for i in range(0, len_s1):
    for j in range(0, len_s1):
        if s1[i] == s2[j]:
            key = key[0:i] + str(j + 1)
print('Key = ', key)
```

Comment: Не надо затенять встроенные функции.

Comment: Да, забыл добавить, есть словарь с наиболее распространёнными словами, такими как: я, по, что, как, нет, или и т.д. Программа должна проверять соответствует ли расшифрованное слово какому либо слову из словаря и, в случае если да, это значит что ключ подобран и на вывод можно подать расшифрованный этим ключом текст.

Comment: @ДанилЕмельянов как на счёт того, что из одних букв можно составить разные слова? Такая проблема у Вас не стоит?

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, некритично в моём случае

Comment: @ДанилЕмельянов тогда Ваша задача решается простым перебором пересечения множеств.